# How to make my own type compatible with a third-party enum?

Tags: typescript

I'm using [cordova-plugin-purchase](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase) which has the following types:

```
    /**
     * Purchase platforms supported by the plugin
     */
    export enum Platform {
        /** Apple AppStore */
        APPLE_APPSTORE = "ios-appstore",
        /** Google Play */
        GOOGLE_PLAY = "android-playstore",
        /** Windows Store */
        WINDOWS_STORE = "windows-store-transaction",
        /** Braintree */
        BRAINTREE = "braintree",
        /** Test platform */
        TEST = "test"
    }


   /** A purchase object returned by the receipt validator */
    interface VerifiedPurchase {
        /** Product identifier */
        id: string;
        /** Platform this purchase was made on */
        platform?: Platform;
     }

/** Reason why a subscription has been canceled */
enum CancelationReason {
    /** Not canceled */
    NOT_CANCELED = "",
    /** Subscription canceled by the developer. */
    DEVELOPER = "Developer",
    /** Subscription canceled by the system for an unspecified reason. */
    SYSTEM = "System",
    /** Subscription upgraded or downgraded to a new subscription. */
    SYSTEM_REPLACED = "System.Replaced",
    /** Product not available for purchase at the time of renewal. */
    SYSTEM_PRODUCT_UNAVAILABLE = "System.ProductUnavailable",
    /** Billing error; for example customer’s payment information is no longer valid. */
    SYSTEM_BILLING_ERROR = "System.BillingError",
    /** Transaction is gone; It has been deleted. */
    SYSTEM_DELETED = "System.Deleted",
    /** Subscription canceled by the user for an unspecified reason. */
    CUSTOMER = "Customer",
    /** Customer canceled their transaction due to an actual or perceived issue within your app. */
    CUSTOMER_TECHNICAL_ISSUES = "Customer.TechnicalIssues",
    /** Customer did not agree to a recent price increase. See also priceConsentStatus. */
    CUSTOMER_PRICE_INCREASE = "Customer.PriceIncrease",
    /** Customer canceled for cost-related reasons. */
    CUSTOMER_COST = "Customer.Cost",
    /** Customer claimed to have found a better app. */
    CUSTOMER_FOUND_BETTER_APP = "Customer.FoundBetterApp",
    /** Customer did not feel he is using this service enough. */
    CUSTOMER_NOT_USEFUL_ENOUGH = "Customer.NotUsefulEnough",
    /** Subscription canceled for another reason; for example, if the customer made the purchase accidentally. */
    CUSTOMER_OTHER_REASON = "Customer.OtherReason",
    /** Subscription canceled for unknown reasons. */
    UNKNOWN = "Unknown"
}
```

In my app, I have a JSON object that contains a verified purchase receipt object.  So I made my own interface based on the cordova-plugin-purchase one like this:

```
export interface PurchaseReceiptVerified {
  id: string;
  platform?: "ios-appstore" | "android-playstore" | "windows-store-transaction" | "braintree" | "test";
  cancelationReason?:
    | ""
    | "Developer"
    | "System"
    | "System.Replaced"
    | "System.ProductUnavailable"
    | "System.BillingError"
    | "System.Deleted"
    | "Customer"
    | "Customer.TechnicalIssues"
    | "Customer.PriceIncrease"
    | "Customer.Cost"
    | "Customer.FoundBetterApp"
    | "Customer.NotUsefulEnough"
    | "Customer.OtherReason"
    | "Unknown";
```

However, when I try to build my app, I get the following error:

```
Type 'PurchaseReceiptVerified | undefined' is not assignable to type 'VerifiedPurchase | undefined'.
  Type 'PurchaseReceiptVerified' is not assignable to type 'VerifiedPurchase'.
    Types of property 'platform' are incompatible.
      Type '"ios-appstore" | "android-playstore" | "windows-store-transaction" | "braintree" | "test" | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Platform | undefined'.
        Type '"ios-appstore"' is not assignable to type 'Platform | undefined'.
```

I don't understand why listing all the values for the cancelationReason enum works, but doing the same for Platform results in an error.  What am I doing wrong here?

I want to maintain my own interface that is a copy of that of cordova-plugin-purchase because I want to get errors in my IDE if the two interfaces ever diverge.

Using TypeScript 5.